# Calculate the array values

Tags: java, arrays

I am having an intro to programming test. These type of questions are going to be on the final exam and I need help going through the process of solving them (finding the array values).

1)

```
int[] array = new int [6]; 


for ( int i = 0 ; i  < array.length ; i++ )
{
  array [i] = i*i;
}

for ( int i = 0 ; i  < array.length ; i = i + 2 )
{
  array[i] = array[i] + array[ i + 1 ];
}
```

The answers that the professor gave. 
i:   4

pos:      0   1   2   3   4   5

values:   1   1  13   9  41  25

2)

```
int[] array = new int [6]; 


for ( int i = 0 ; i  < array.length ; i++ )
{
  array [i] = i*i;
}

for ( int i = 0 ; i  < array.length ; i = i + 2 )
{
  array[array.length - 1 - i] = array[i] + array[ i + 1 ];
}
```

again the answers
i:   4

pos:      0   1   2   3   4   5

values:   0  17   4  13  16   1

I can get some of the answers but not all. I need to know how to solve these types of problems by hand, not compiler.

Comment: By hand, this becomes a simple problem of logic...

Comment: Is there some Java syntax you don't understand, and if so, what?  It doesn't help to say "I can get some of the answers but not all", because we're not mind readers and can't figure out just what it is you don't get right.  Thanks.

Comment: Yes for instance if I were to find the array value for position zero, I would take the array[i]=0*0 and get 0;. I would then move to the second for loop and do the calculation and would get an answer of 1 which is the wrong answer. (Second question.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good day,

Here are few important concepts you need to understand when solving these problems:

In Java, like many other programming languages, the first index of an array is always ''0''. Therefore, when you are iterating through the various cells of an array, you always start at 0 up to the (size-1) of the array.

The .length is a static field that returns the size of the array.

Therefore if we take your first problem:

```
int[] array = new int [6]; 

// Size of the array is 6, so array.length returns 6
// Which also means that valid cells are from 0 to 5 inclusively.

// Here we say, for i that starts at 0, as long as i is smaller than 6 (your array
// length, perform the body of the loop. Everytime you do it, increase i by 1.

for ( int i = 0 ; i  < array.length ; i++ ) 
{
      array [i] = i*i; 
}


//This does the following:
// array[0] = 0*0; -> array[0] = 0;
// array[1] = 1*1; -> array[1] = 1;
// array[2] = 2*2; -> array[2] = 4;
// array[3] = 3*3; -> array[3] = 9;
// array[4] = 4*4; -> array[4] = 16;
// array[5] = 5*5; -> array[5] = 25;
// and the loop stops.

//Now the second loop: same thing as the first loop but we increase i by 2 instead of 1

for ( int i = 0 ; i  < array.length ; i = i + 2 )
{
      array[i] = array[i] + array[ i + 1 ];
}

// This does the following:
// array[0] = array[0] + array[0+1] -> array[0] = 0 + 1; -> array[0] = 1;
// array[2] = array[2] + array[1+1] -> array[2] = 4 + 9; -> array[2] = 13
// array[4] = array[4] + array[4+1] -> array[4] = 16 + 25 -> array[4] = 41
// And we stop because i=4, so i= i+2 = 6, which is larger than array.length (5)
```

Therefore we have:

```
array[0] = 1
array[1] = 1
array[2] = 13
array[3] = 9
array[4] = 41
array[5] = 25
```

I hope this helps and good luck with your test,

Alex

Comment: Thanks this helped a lot. For some reason the other questions worked without me going through the loop. (brainfried). Now I did the easier ones with going through the loop and was able to solve them!!

Answer (score 1):

Well since your question is about how to solve these questions by hand I would suggest the following:

Once you get to the question write the array on a piece of paper and make a new line for each index. So if your array is say `int [] array = new int [4]` you would write:

> array[0] =
>       array[1] =
>       array[2] =
>       array[3] =

Then you go through the program step by step in your head, and whenever there is an assignment to an array location you write it in the corresponding line. Now if there was already a value in there, you simply cross the value, and write the new value to the right of if on the same line.

That way you might end up with something like this:

> array[0] =  <s>1 3 5 1</s>  3
>   array[1] =  <s>5 1</s>  2
>   array[2] =  <s>53 3</s>  35
>   array[3] = 2

The final values will always be the ones on the very right. I find this technique to be the most handy and also the quickest (which is always important during an exam). You can also retrace your steps by looking at the crossed out values in case you're second guessing yourself.

Answer (score 0):

In the first problem :

first loop is just iterating the array and and filling the array.. which is multiplying the index by itself

so the array would be 0*0, 1*1, 2*2,3*3,4*4,5*5

and in second loop  i is  incremented by 2 places so, we would only modify 0,2,4 positions of the array. 0th position would be 0+1=1, 2nd position would be , 4+9 =13, 4rd position would be, 16+25 =41; this is the reason the final array is 1,1,13,9,41,25

In the second problem: the first loop does the same job as in first problem;
In second loop the loop will be executed thrice, for i =0,2,4.
after first loop array values are 0,1,4,9,16

```
for i=0 ; array[6-1-0]=array[0]+array[1]=> array[5]=0+1 =1;
for i=2 ; array[6-1-2]=array[2]+array[3]=> array[3]=4+9 = 13;
for i=4 ; array[6-1-4]=array[4]+array[5]=> array[1]=16+1= 17;
```

so the final array would be: 0,17,4,13,16,1

In would advice you to closely check how the loop is being iterated.. It is advisable to use paper in exam to solve these kind of problems